# discord.py make a bot join a set voice channel, not necessarily the channel of the person running the command

Tags: python, discord.py

```
voice_channel = bot.get_channel('channel id')
await voice_channel.connect()
```

I want to make a bot join a specific voice channel when given a command, but the above code gives error "Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'connect'".

How do I make it so that the bot can join the correct specified voice channel?

Comment: Parameter to [get_channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel) should be an int. Are you using a string?

Answer (score 1):

[`bot.get_channel()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel)
takes an **Int**, not a **String**. It seems from your example code that you are passing the ID as a string. Try this instead:

```py
# Replace the long number with your desired channel ID.
voice_channel = bot.get_channel(671603729965341934)

# Connect to the channel. Remember that non-existent
# or deleted channels also return as None.
await voice_channel.connect()
```

Comment: Glad to hear that! Remember to mark it as the answer if everything is good now.